# while building an application logic (use macros in a custom pallet)

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, substrate-node, blockchain, block

[image: After making below changes i got these errors how can i fix this.][[image: I got this error when i run this command cargo check -p node-template-runtime --release]][in build an application logic im facing this error im new to substrate please help me fix this.]

Comment: What polkadot version that you are working on ? I think you are working on with newer version (polkadot-v1.0.0 or newer). `type BlockNumber` is deprecated in frame_system::Config.

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.BlockNumberProvider.html#associatedtype.BlockNumber

Answer (score 0):

Import:

`use frame_system::pallet_prelude::BlockNumberFor;`

How to fix:

Change `T::BlockNumber` to `BlockNumberFor<T>`

Comment: After making above changes im getting more errors

Comment: May you send me your github link ?

Comment: This is the node template im cloning ......git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

Comment: But I dont see any onchain storage configuration related to the `StorageMap` you captured in the screenshot

Comment: Then how can i fix this issue are there any other methods

Comment: please give us your github link.

Comment: Sir actually im following susbstrate documentation in that im cloning and using code ...

Comment: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/main/pallets/template/src    (this is the github link)